# Python how to fix 'ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence' on a Pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

'''
I'm trying to create bins based on the 'Position'  column on df.groupby('Chrom') object.
I've been struggling for hours on the last part of my code.The purpose of the script is to retrieve the lowest pvalue (p) for each group of the groupby object.
**df_lowestP = data.loc[data.groupby('Bin_labels')['p'].idxmin()]** raised the following error '**ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence**'
I'm not sure how to identify the empty sequences and how to sort it out.
Thank you in advance for helping me out.

'''

```
cols= ['Chrom', 'Position', 'Marker', 'p']
vals = [['5A', 70.86, 'wsnp_Ex_c2474_4619730', 0.952967047],\
['2D', 80.46, 'Excalibur_c48871_1330', 0.603140475],\
['5B', 21.6, 'BS00010491_51', 0.68806773],\
['1D', 7.47, 'BobWhite_c4303_524', 0.14664623599999999],\
['6B', 52.36, 'RAC875_c54904_460', 0.747116322],\
['1B', 56.92, 'BS00023044_51', 0.793591901],\
['1B', 82.21, 'Excalibur_c60931_1260', 0.10407994],\
['7B', 61.76, 'Kukri_c12822_132', 0.9914339959999999],\
['6B', 99.03, 'BS00069285_51', 0.591267434],\
['6B', 65.68, 'Tdurum_contig42414_612', 0.6802424490000001],\
['2A', 0.0, 'wsnp_Ex_c1962_3696626', 0.016681088],\
['2D', 88.72, 'BS00031459_51', 0.06155213599999999],\
['3B', 60.02, 'RAC875_c2787_470', 0.359986433],\
['2B', 89.94, 'Excalibur_c16646_1254', 0.548888715],\
['6D', 48.85, 'Excalibur_c8134_1319', 0.4144683],\
['5B', 9.03, 'wsnp_Ex_c2459_4591587', 0.64927464],\
['5B', 123.43, 'BS00021868_51', 0.478334741],\
['2A', 194.55, 'wsnp_CAP11_rep_c6137_2841945', 0.67702519],\
['2B', 97.48, 'RAC875_c46788_60', 0.461550513],\
['1A', 73.26, 'CAP7_c3269_236', 0.8397169459999999],\
['1B', 148.6, 'RAC875_c9082_267', 0.992387433],\
['3A', 158.94, 'RAC875_c3084_415', 0.35521176200000004],\
['2A', 77.73, 'Kukri_c7139_1248', 0.865599771],\
['4A', 55.63, 'wsnp_Ex_c829_1620518', 0.628465917],\
['4A', 61.94, 'Excalibur_c96303_224', 0.8707948609999999],\
['1A', 85.79, 'Excalibur_c13183_128', 0.811616063],\
['3A', 79.22, 'wsnp_Ex_c32003_40728918', 0.45561401100000004],\
['7B', 29.87, 'Excalibur_c54242_704', 0.165007274],\
['6B', 75.73, 'Kukri_c60169_54', 0.893133473],\
['7B', 94.94, 'BS00065981_51', 0.45571674],\
['6A', 64.26, 'GENE-3933_586', 0.974289783],\
['1B', 0.0, 'Kukri_c44369_131', 0.311861047],\
['5D', 9.36, 'IACX2960', 0.9434061220000001],\
['6D', 48.34, 'Ex_c12134_939', 0.456392529],\
['3B', 97.16, 'wsnp_Ex_c18915_27811736', 0.785250982],\
['5B', 166.0, 'BS00098520_51', 0.6439036220000001],\
['2B', 96.44, 'RAC875_rep_c111100_447', 0.063204845],\
['1A', 51.88, 'Kukri_c3150_341', 0.17333784600000002],\
['5A', 139.08, 'BS00010179_51', 0.8453566920000001],\
['1B', 126.13, 'wsnp_Ku_c18881_28259811', 0.653103781],\
['1B', 128.64, 'Excalibur_c8585_701', 0.103269216],\
['2D', 44.17, 'Excalibur_c40820_335', 0.08864491],\
['1B', 80.3, 'Kukri_c5335_2165', 0.567401681],\
['3A', 97.15, 'RAC875_c62012_382', 0.407825859],\
['4B', 52.36, 'GENE-0037_298', 0.014111186999999999],\
['5A', 79.55, 'Tdurum_contig59930_366', 0.117716542],\
['5B', 128.25, 'BS00028082_51', 0.24427141],\
['7B', 109.87, 'wsnp_Ku_rep_c103690_90365438', 0.670004615],\
['2D', 89.68, 'BS00066526_51', 0.025921416],\
['7A', 81.25, 'IAAV5328', 0.340900239]]

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols)

for gp,data in df.groupby('Chrom'):
    pos_range = data['Position'].max() - data['Position'].min()
    inter_value = 5 
    min_value = int(np.floor(data['Position'].min()))
    max_value = int(np.ceil(data['Position'].max()))
    intervals = [i for i in range(min_value, max_value+inter_value, inter_value)] #creating bins boundaries
    labels = ['Bin_' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(intervals))] #labelling bins
    #creating bin_labels column
    bin_labels = pd.cut(x=data['Position'],
                                    bins=intervals,
                                    labels=labels,
                                    include_lowest=True)
    # creating bin boundaries column
    bin_range = pd.cut(x=data['Position'],
                             bins=intervals,
                             include_lowest=True)

    data.insert(3,'Bin_labels',bin_labels)
    data.insert(4,'Bin_range',bin_range)
    
    #Retrieving a single marker with lowest P for each bin
    df_lowestP = data.loc[data.groupby('Bin_labels')['p'].idxmin()] #Here is the trouble
```

Comment: your question likely won't be answered if you don't provide a minimum reproducible example with input and expected output (no images!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: yes you are right. I've just edited my post to get the error reproducible. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Bin_labels` is categorical type. It includes other bin with value NaN.  Therefore, you got empty sequences.  When you groupby `Bin_labels`, you lost original indices.

To fix this, we have to save the original indices, sort the data by `Bin_labels` and `p`, group by `Bin_labels`, and take the first entry. Not sure if it is the best solution.

```
data['idx'] = data.index
data = data.sort_values(['Bin_labels', 'p'])
idx = data.groupby('Bin_labels').first()['idx'].dropna()
df_lowestP = data.loc[idx]
```

Here is the second group.

Original:

```
Name: idx, dtype: float64
   Chrom  Position                   Marker Bin_labels       Bin_range         p  idx
31    1B      0.00         Kukri_c44369_131      Bin_1   (-0.001, 5.0]  0.311861   31
5     1B     56.92            BS00023044_51     Bin_12    (55.0, 60.0]  0.793592    5
6     1B     82.21    Excalibur_c60931_1260     Bin_17    (80.0, 85.0]  0.104080    6
42    1B     80.30         Kukri_c5335_2165     Bin_17    (80.0, 85.0]  0.567402   42
40    1B    128.64      Excalibur_c8585_701     Bin_26  (125.0, 130.0]  0.103269   40
39    1B    126.13  wsnp_Ku_c18881_28259811     Bin_26  (125.0, 130.0]  0.653104   39
20    1B    148.60         RAC875_c9082_267     Bin_30  (145.0, 150.0]  0.992387   20
```

Lowest:

```
     Chrom  Position                 Marker Bin_labels       Bin_range         p  idx
31.0    1B      0.00       Kukri_c44369_131      Bin_1   (-0.001, 5.0]  0.311861   31
5.0     1B     56.92          BS00023044_51     Bin_12    (55.0, 60.0]  0.793592    5
6.0     1B     82.21  Excalibur_c60931_1260     Bin_17    (80.0, 85.0]  0.104080    6
40.0    1B    128.64    Excalibur_c8585_701     Bin_26  (125.0, 130.0]  0.103269   40
20.0    1B    148.60       RAC875_c9082_267     Bin_30  (145.0, 150.0]  0.992387   20
```